# Find unknown distribution of X when Z=XY and Z and Y are known?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

Given X, Y and Z are random variables, if the probability distributions of Y & Z are known, is it possible to estimate (a likely distribution for) X if Z = XY and X and Y are independent?

Comment: It would help to know the joint distribution of $(Y,Z)$.  Do you?  If not, things are still ok provided $Y$ and $Z$ are positive variables. Otherwise, in some cases no unique solution is possible.

Comment: The distribution for X is the distribution of Z/Y. This is true whether or not X and Y are independent.  But as @whuber says this requires knowing the joint distribution of Y and Z.

Comment: Thank you! Well, alas, I don't know the joint distribution of (Y,Z), although I might be able to estimate it, Y is positive but Z contains negatives and positives, as should X. I envisaged perhaps no unique solution, but is there some kind of way to estimate a likely or most likely distribution for X?